# How can access to ONU device while connected with router via wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, openwrt, private-network

My router has OpenWRT installed and my ONU device is connected through a wire on the WAN port. I can configure the ONU via 192.168.100.1 if I connect directly to my PC via LAN port and set my computer IP to 192.168.100.10. How can I access the ONU device while the ONU is connected to the router and My PC is connected to the router's wifi/lan?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the same 192.168.100.10 as an additional IP address on the router's WAN interface. OpenWRT calls this configuration "[aliases](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/network_interface_alias)".

The mechanism is the same – the device that's adjacent to the ONU (whether it's the PC or the router) needs to know that it *is* in fact adjacent to the ONU network-wise, and vice versa.

Comment: Hey @user1686, I tried that but no hope. Maybe some firewall issue or port forwarding thing to consider also?

Comment: Make sure NAT (masquerading) is enabled for this alias interface as well (the same way as it is enabled for the regular WAN interface) – the ONT doesn't know how to reach your PC's IP address back, so the router needs to masquerade the source IP.